# I want to learn how to create and compile multiple files in one c++ project using visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner learning to code in C++

I use Windows 10 to learn code

I want to learn how to create, link and run multiple files in Visual Studio Code.

I'm currently learning on Codecademy

I'm stuck on the Header section where they teach you how to link multiple files.

here is the link for that section:

https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-c-plus-plus/lessons/cpp-functions-scope-flexiblity/exercises/cpp-functions-header-files

Problem:

I want to practice using Visual Studio Code but I don't know how to link or make header files and I'm not finding any tutorials and I'm at a sticking point.

Progress:

I know how to create a Make file but I don't know how to create, open and link multiple new files and use them in a Visual Studio Code

Can anyone show me how to do this

Comment: See this: https://dev.to/talhabalaj/setup-visual-studio-code-for-multi-file-c-projects-1jpi

Comment: Assuming that you can run single-file project in vscode. You don't need a Makefile right now. You just need to configure your vscode the following 3 files: c_cpp_properties.json/launch.json/tasks.json. Search templates for them. Learn how to write a Makefile after you get all this working.

Comment: Have you already checked this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_create-hello-world?

Comment: So far I've used this link 
                                                                                    
nowhttps://dev.to/talhabalaj/setup-visual-studio-code-for-multi-file-c-projects-1jpi

Comment: When I use that method though its giving me this fatal error message,

Comment: compilation terminated.
src/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: HelloWorld.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "HelloWorld.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o obj/main.o -c src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: HelloWorld.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "HelloWorld.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:47: obj/main.o] Error 1
PS C:\Users\86135\Documents\Programming\Hello World>

Comment: I'll try the method that works just want to try one at a time to solve it